# What causes this "Cast to ObjectId" error in a Express.js application?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a blogging application with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

In my `posts.js` controller I have:

```
exports.addPostForm = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('addpost', {
        website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
        page_heading: 'Add New Post'
    });
};
```

The form in the `addpost` view:

```
<form method="post" action="postadded" name="sentMessage" class="w-100" novalidate>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Post title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post title" name="title" id="title" required>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Post summary</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Post summary" name="summary" id="summary" required>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Post content</label>
            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Post content" name="full_text" id="fullText" required></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addPostButton">Add Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

It the routes I have:

```
router.get('/addpost', postsController.addPostForm);
```

Finally, the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    short_description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    full_text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

I thought nothing was missing an yet I get this error in the console:

```
'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "addpost" at path "_id" for model "Post"'
```

What is missing?

Comment: Where's your controller addPost with `POST` method. Can you add it in your question?

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula There is no `addPost` method yet, there's only `addPostForm` that should render the form. (there are also `getPosts` and `getSinglePost`).

Comment: In your html form, you've add `Post` method and action `postAdded` then you have to create that method.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula I checked and it is not that.

Comment: You can check your code above for an example html.

Comment: You can check your code above for an example html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused because there are function with :id param and handled with controller which gets an object like that

```
router.get('/:id', postsController.controllerFunction);
```

and the /addpost trait as a param not a path
try to change the order of the routes

Answer (score 0):

seems like somewhere in your code you are trying to get some document from db with mongoose model but passing wrong argument. instead of valid mongo ObjectId value "addpost" is passed

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding new post method must be post in your route instead of get.